# How do i put this email data in a table format?

Tags: php, forms, email

I am currently receiving data from a form through php email as follows...

```
$message = "$groomName and $brideName ; $weddingDate \n 
How did you hear?: $howDidYouHear \n 
~WEDDING INFO~ \n Date of Wedding: $weddingDate \n 
Time of Wedding: $weddingTime \n 
Location of Ceremony: $ceremonyLocation \n 
Location of Reception: $receptionLocation \n 
Additional Locations: $additionalLocation \n 
# of Guests: $guests \n 
~BRIDE INFO~ \n Bride's Name: $brideName \n 
Bride's Cell: $brideCell \n 
Bride's Email: $brideEmail \n 
Bride's Address: $brideAddress \n 
# of Bridesmaids: $bridesMaidsNum \n 
Names of Bridesmaids: $bridesMaidsNames \n 
Location of Bride Prep: $bridePrep \n 
~GROOM INFO~ \n 
Groom's Name: $groomName \n 
Groom's Cell: $groomCell \n 
Groom's Email: $groomEmail \n 
Groom's Address: $groomAddress \n 
# of Groomsmen: $groomsmenNum \n 
Names of Groomsmen: $groomsmenNames \n 
Location of Groom Prep: $groomPrep \n 
~KEY NAMES~ \n 
Maid of Honor: $maidOfHonor \n 
Best Man: $bestMan \n 
Bride's Parents: $brideParents \n 
Groom's Parents: $groomParents \n 
Flower Girl: $flowerGirl \n 
Ring Bearer: $ringBearer \n 
KEY DETAILS \n 
Ceremony Setting: $setting \n 
Ceremony Restrictions: $restrictions \n 
Details: $details \n 
3 Emotions: $emotions \n 
Shoot Type: $shootType \n 
Location of Family Photos: $familyPhotos \n 
Do You Know What a First Look is?: $knowFirstLook \n 
Will there be a first look?: $firstLook \n 
Important Photos: $importantPhotos \n 
What to incorporate: $incorporate \n ".
```

I want to receive the email in an html format like the following...

```
<table width="600px" cellpadding="2" border="1" cellspacing="0" style="font-size:12px; border:1px solid black">
        <tr><td colspan="4" style="background:black; color:white; text-align:center; font-size:18px;">Pre-Wedding Questionnaire</td></tr>
        <tr><th colspan="3"  style="font-size:16px;">$brideName and $groomName</th><th width="25%" style="font-size:16px;">$weddingDate</th></tr>
        <tr><td width="25%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">How did you hear:</td><td colspan="3">$howDidYouHear</td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="4" align="left" style="font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; font-family:Helvetica, sans-sarif; padding-left:40px;">~Wedding Info~</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Date of Wedding:</td><td colspan="3">$weddingDate</td></tr>
        <tr><td style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Time of Wedding:</td><td colspan="3">$weddingTime</td></tr>
        <tr><td style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Location of Ceremony:</td><td colspan="3">$ceremonyLocation</td></tr>
        <tr><td style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Location of Reception:</td><td colspan="3">$receptionLocation</td></tr>
        <tr><td style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Additional Location:</td><td colspan="3">$additionalLocation</td></tr>
        <tr><td style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;"># of Guests:</td><td colspan="3">$guests</td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="4" align="left" style="font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; font-family:Helvetica, sans-sarif; padding-left:40px;">~Bride Info~</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Bride"s Name:</td><td colspan="3">$brideName</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Bride"s Cell:</td><td colspan="3">$brideCell</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Bride"s Email:</td><td colspan="3">$brideEmail</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Bride"s Address:</td><td colspan="3">$brideAddress</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;"># of Bridesmaids:</td><td colspan="3">$bridesMaidsNum</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Names of Bridesmaids:</td><td colspan="3">$bridesMaidsNames</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Location of Bride Prep:</td><td colspan="3">$bridePrep</td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="4" align="left" style="font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; font-family:Helvetica, sans-sarif; padding-left:40px;">~Groom Info~</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Groom"s Name:</td><td colspan="3">$groomName</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Groom"s Cell:</td><td colspan="3">$groomCell</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Groom"s Email:</td><td colspan="3">$groomEmail</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Groom"s Address:</td><td colspan="3">$groomAddress</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;"># of Groomsmen:</td><td colspan="3">$groomsmenNum</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Names of Groomsmen:</td><td colspan="3">$groomsmenNames</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Location of Groom Prep:</td><td colspan="3">$groomPrep</td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="4" align="left" style="font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; font-family:Helvetica, sans-sarif; padding-left:40px;">~Key Names~</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Maid of Honor:</td><td colspan="3">$maidOfHonor</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Best Man:</td><td colspan="3">$bestMan</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Bride"s Parents:</td><td colspan="3">$brideParents</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Groom"s Parents:</td><td colspan="3">$groomParents</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Flower Girl:</td><td colspan="3">$flowerGirl</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Ring Bearer:</td><td colspan="3">$ringBearer</td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="4" align="left" style="font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; font-family:Helvetica, sans-sarif; padding-left:40px;">~Key Details~</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Ceremony Setting:</td><td colspan="3">$settings</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Ceremony Restrictions:</td><td colspan="3">$restrictions</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Details:</td><td colspan="3">$details</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">3 Emotions:</td><td colspan="3">$emotions</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Shoot Type:</td><td colspan="3">$shootType</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Location of Family Photos:</td><td colspan="3">$familyPhotos</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Do you know what a first look is:</td><td colspan="3">$knowFirstLook</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Will There Be a First Look:</td><td colspan="3">$firstLook</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">Important Photos:</td><td colspan="3">$importantPhotos</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="20%" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold;">What to incorporate:</td><td colspan="3">$incorporate</td></tr>
</table>
```

I have tried looking at 1 million forums and tutorials to try and figure this out with 0 luck and a lot of frustration. Can someone please help guide me in this. I thank you so much ahead of time.

Comment: Whats not working?

Comment: The real problem is how you are receiving your data; the `<form>` is posting that whopping amount of data as a single `$_POST` variable. You'll want to update your form to give the user **options**, assigning each `<input>` an independent `name` attribute (which will map to a unique `$_POST` variable), rather than simply give them one giant text box to enter all of their relevant information. Then you can craft the PHP to output the data in the desired format much more easily.

Comment: Thanks you for your input Obsidian Age. But my actual <form> On the HTML page does have have assigned name attributes. The form and email works great. I just want to structure the email I receive in a table format.